# AddRelativeForce() does not add the force relatively

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have want to add force to a Rigidbody by dragging mouse on the screen.
even though I have transformed screen coordinates to the world coordinates and rotation of the Rigidbody looks at the coordinates where the mouse button is released, When I add relative force by AddRelativeForce ball goes directly forward.

```cs
public GameObject ballPrefab;
GameObject ballInstance;

private float force=15;
Vector3 mouseStart;
Vector3 mouseStop;
float minDragDistance=15f;
float zDepth=20f;

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        mouseStart = Input.mousePosition;
    }
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        mouseStop = Input.mousePosition;

        if(Vector3.Distance(mouseStop, mouseStart) > minDragDistance)
        {
            //Here I am getting the position on screen coordinates to throw the rigidbody to                
            Vector3 hitPos = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, zDepth);

            //I transform screen coordinates to world coordinates
            Vector3 hitPoss = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(hitPos);
            //transforming rigidbody to look at hitpos direction             
            ballInstance.transform.LookAt(hitPoss);
            //adding relative force
            ballInstance.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddRelativeForce(Vector3.forward * force, ForceMode.Force);
        }
    }
}
```

As I commented in the code I change the `transform.rotation` properties of my game object with `LookAt()` function and when I check the inspector it changes the rotation just right. but by  `AddRelativeForce(Vector3.forward)` it directly goes forward on global z direction instead of locally changed z direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AddRelativeForce` applies a force relative to the parent object's orientation, which doesn't really make sense here, since there is no parent object.
Instead of:

```
ballInstance.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddRelativeForce(Vector3.forward * force, ForceMode.Force);
```

Try:

```
ballInstance.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(ballInstance.transform.forward * force, ForceMode.Force);
```

This should work, since instead of using the global forward Vector `Vector3.forward`, you are using the forward Vector of your ballInstance `ballInstance.transform.forward`

Answer (score 0):

Changing the transform won't take effect instantly, you should set `Rigidbody.rotation` instead.

Check the document: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-rotation.html